# JBoss Servername

Tags: jboss5.x

Where do you change the hostname(servername) for your application server. For example, if there is an application server JBoss which is running on local machine, port 8080 and is accessed using "http://localhost:8080/index.jsp, and if I want to change lets say to "http://www.myserver.com/index.jsp, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is called "virtual hosting".  You can find the instructions for doing this with JBoss 5.1 [here](http://www.openscope.net/2010/01/17/virtual-hosting-with-jboss/).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This would certainly b very helpful.